# Using polyglossia with Hebrew as second language mess up align environment

Tags: polyglossia, hebrew

*Edit:* the problem appears when using xelatex from TL 2015, when using xelatex from TL 2017 everything is fine.

Here is a working example

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}


\begin{document}
\begin{align}
1 + 1 = 2
\\
1 + 2 = 3
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

And here is how the align environment looks like
[image]

after removing

```
 \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
```

I'm getting the desired result:

[image]

How can I use Hebrew without messing up the numbering of the align environment?

Thank you,

Gilad

Comment: Do you compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? What version of each are you using? What are your package versions? (Add `\listfiles` to the beginning of the test file to get a table of package versions like in Herbert's answer at the end of the `.log` file)

Comment: With LuaLaTeX 1.09 (MikTeX 2.9 on Win 10 fully updated this morning) the example fails to compile due to undefined control sequences in `polyglossia` files. With XeLaTeX 0.999991 the example compiles fine and the parentheses show up as expected. I guess this is a version problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with XeLaTeX. What TeX distribution are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
```

with up-to-date TL2018:

[image]

```
*File List*
  report.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 amsmath.sty    2018/12/01 v2.17b AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
polyglossia.sty    2018/04/07 v1.43 Alternative to Babel for XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
eX
etoolbox.sty    2018/08/19 v2.5f e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
makecmds.sty    2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
fontspec.sty    2018/07/30 vv2.6h Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
  xparse.sty    2018-10-17 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2019-01-01 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2019-01-01 L3 programming layer 
l3xdvipdfmx.def    
fontspec-xetex.sty    2018/07/30 vv2.6h Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

 fontenc.sty
   tuenc.def    2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
fontspec.cfg
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
gloss-english.ldf    polyglossia: module for english
gloss-hebrew.ldf    polyglossia: module for hebrew
hebrewcal.sty    2015/04/17 v2.6 Hebrew calendar for polyglossia (adapted from 
hebcal.sty in Babel)
    bidi.sty    2018/12/11 v35.4 Bidirectional typesetting in plain TeX and LaT
eX
   iftex.sty    2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX,
 and LuaTeX
biditools.sty    2018/12/11 v1.9 Programming tools for bidi package
zref-abspage.sty    2018/11/21 v2.27 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2018/11/21 v2.27 Module base for zref (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
latex-xetex-bidi.def    2018/10/11 v1.3.6 bidi adaptations for `latex.ltx' for 
XeTeX engine
footnote-xetex-bidi.def    2017/08/09 v1.1 bidi footnote macros for XeTeX engin
e
report-xetex-bidi.def    2017/06/09 v0.8 bidi adaptations for standard report c
lass for XeTeX engine
amsmath-xetex-bidi.def    2018/01/08 v1.1 bidi adaptations for amsmath package 
for XeTeX engine
amstext-xetex-bidi.def    2016/09/12 v0.2 bidi adaptations for amstext package 
for XeTeX engine
loadingorder-xetex-bidi.def    2017/12/29 v0.97 making sure that bidi is the la
st package loaded
cal-util.def
babel-hebrewalph.def    2010/03/02 Babel definitions for Hebrew numerals
 Adapted from hebrew.ldf (2005/03/30 v2.3h)
 ***********
```

Comment: Getting the same result even when adding `\setmainlanguage{english}`.